# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement whenever I add data

Tags: sql

I get an error in Visual Studio whenever I submit data on access. Need help tried everything on google but it still happens. Thank you

```
Private Sub btn_save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_save.Click
    If txtLot.Text = "" And cmbPartsList.Text = "" And txtYear.Text = "" And txtDate.Text = "" And txtMonth.Text = "" And txtOperator.Text = "" And txtInput.Text = "" And txtOutput.Text = "" Then
        LBLMSG.Text = "The " & txtPartName.Text & " has been added to the inventory."
        LBLMSG.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine
        LBLMSG.ForeColor = Color.Black
        cmbPartsList.Focus()
        Beep()
    Else
        query = "SELECT * FROM ProdOutput1 WHERE HELPERKEY='" & txtLot.Text + "-" + txtPartNumber.Text + "-" + txtProcess.Text + "-" + txtYear.Text + txtMonth.Text + txtDate.Text + txtShift.Text & "'"
        retrieveSingleResult(query)

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            LBLMSG.Text = "The " & txtPartName.Text & " have duplicate data, Please Check Again."
            LBLMSG.BackColor = Color.Red
            LBLMSG.ForeColor = Color.White
            Beep()
        Else
            fields = "DATEENCODED, PROCESS, LOTNUMBER, INPUT, OUTPUT, PARTNUMBER, PARTNAME, OPERATOR, ENTRYDATE, LOTNUMBERANDPARTNUMBER, REJECTS, HELPER, LOTMONTHANDYEAR, INTDATE, SHIFT, PROCMONTH, PARTSLIST, ENTRYYEAR, MONTHPROC, MACHINE, HELPERKEY"
            fvalue = dtpEntryDate.Value & "','" & txtProcess.Text & "','" & txtLot.Text & "','" & txtInput.Text & "','" & txtOutput.Text & "','" & txtPartNumber.Text & "','" & txtPartName.Text & "','" & txtOperator.Text & "','" & txtYear.Text & txtMonth.Text & txtDate.Text & txtShift.Text & "','" & txtLot.Text & "-" & txtPartNumber.Text & "','" & txtReject.Text & "','" & txtLot.Text & "-" & txtPartNumber.Text & "-" & txtProcess.Text & "','" & "HTI" & txtYear.Text & txtMonth.Text & "','" & txtDate.Text & "','" & txtShift.Text & "','" & txtYear.Text & txtMonth.Text & "','" & cmbPartsList.Text & "','" & txtYear.Text & "','" & txtMonth.Text & "','" & txtMCLot.Text & "','" & txtLot.Text & "-" & txtPartNumber.Text & "-" & txtProcess.Text & "-" & txtYear.Text & txtMonth.Text & txtDate.Text & txtShift.Text
            query = "INSERT INTO ProdOutput1 (" & fields & ") VALUES ('" & fvalue & "')"
            cudfunctionNOmsg(query)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Syntax Error in INSERT INTO Statement, sorry I thought I added the error

Comment: In between the line beginning `query = "...` and `cudfunctionNOmsg(query)`, add `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(query)` (this will display `query` in the Debug Window) and check to ensure the format of the INSERT query is valid. The error is showing that there is a syntax error with the query, which is usually punctuation not matching, things like that.

Comment: I rechecked the query, but I can't find any problem.

Comment: I added the system.diagnostics but still posting same error

Comment: DATEENCODED, PROCESS, LOTNUMBER, INPUT, OUTPUT, PARTNUMBER, PARTNAME, OPERATOR, ENTRYDATE, LOTNUMBERANDPARTNUMBER, REJECTS, HELPER, LOTMONTHANDYEAR, INTDATE, SHIFT, PROCMONTH, PARTSLIST, ENTRYYEAR, MONTHPROC, MACHINE, HELPERKEY) VALUES ('5/7/2021 10:45:45 AM','MACHINING','HTI2122AE00001','123','123','170274300','HEATSINK BA; PH','TSET','2122A','HTI2122AE00001-170274300','0','HTI2122AE00001-170274300-MACHINING','HTI212','2','A','212','170274300-HEATSINK BA; PH','21','2','E','HTI2122AE00001-170274300-MACHINING-2122A')

Comment: Does the query work if you try to run it manually against the DB? Also not sure which DBMS you are using with the VB, so I can't tell, but the Date format could perhaps cause it!?

Comment: Solved it. I renamed the OutPut and Input on access db and my code. I don't why, but I read that changing common names can help.

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :)

Comment: Please never say you got an error.  Cut & paste the exact error so that we can see what it says.  If we can't see the error, we can't tell what the problem is.  It's like taking your car to the mechanic and saying "The car makes a noise" but not telling what the noise is.

Comment: Yeah/ Sorry about that. I was in hurry. Will never happenagain. thanks

Comment: Also my title is the error I am encountering

Comment: Can you rebuild this to use parameters? Now you are vulnerable to "[sql injection](https://bobby-tables.com/)" - try and use a `'` (single quote) in one of your textbox values

Comment: FYI `OUTPUT` is a [reserved word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/sql-reserved-words#n-p) in Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I renamed the OutPut and Input on access db and my code. I don't why, but I read that changing common names can help.